Movie about car thieves who take a woman and her kids hostage
The movie is about 3 thieves. Their boss asks them to steal a specific car brand. After they find it, they see the car driver (a woman) enter her house. They follow her to steal the car but a cop spots them and follows them. The cop calls for backup, but the thieves notice this and shoots him by mistake. The cop manages to shoot one of the 3 thieves.  
They realized they have got themselves into deep trouble, so they take the woman hostage in her own house. Her daughter is having a party with her girlfriends, who are taken hostage as well. At the end of the movie the 2 men are murdered by the woman.
The woman worked as a nurse and she had a son who was deaf.

Language? Year?

Though I agree the question needs some specifics, it didn't really deserve the downvotes since it provides a pretty detailed plot synopsis.

Sounds like Home Invasion from 1997. From an online synopsis:

Teenager Willow Patchett (Bonnie Root) and her mother Georgia (Veronica Hamel) seldom see eye to eye on anything. But both Willow and Georgia are forced to form a united front to save their lives when three desperate thieves (one of them mortally wounded) invade the Patchett household on the same night that Willow is throwing a party for her friends. As the authorities outside try to negotiate a rescue with a minimum of bloodshed, the hostages desperately formulate their own plan for escape. This TV movie throws in everything from a hearing-impaired kid brother to bikini-clad high school girls to sustain audience interest. 

This happens after a botched car theft. Here are the mother and daughter:

